# Increment index for getOwnPropertyNames in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

With this array-like object can get the index for every property, but can not output the result when log the object. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Array-like object
var pickedCards = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(pickedCards).forEach(function(val) {
  val++;
  return pickedCards[val];
});

console.log(pickedCards);
```

Comment: indexes are strings, not numbers, and as such, they are immutable.

Comment: Ehhh, what exactly is it you're trying to do here ???

Comment: you want to change the keys?

Comment: I need to increase the 0 property to 1, 1 to 2, etc

Comment: You want to *reassign* every property value to a one-larger property name, correct? i.e., produce `{ 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c' }`

Comment: yes @apsillers Exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
var pickedCards = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' }, pickedCardsChanges = {};

for(var card in pickedCards){
  pickedCardsChanges[+card + 1] = pickedCards[card]
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(pickedCardsChanges))
```